# How to authenticate against the OneDrive API in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, onedrive

All,

I am trying to build a library for onedrive.

Not to give too much detail but I have constructed the request and if I call this from a browser everything works fine, and i eventually get a json response.

https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://someaddress.com/redirect.html

My problem is that I cannot get the authorization code in python using urllib2 and geturl() method as the redirect that yields the code is not seen by urllib2.

When I call the geturl() method I get the original url, not the redirect url containing the code.

Regards,
Frage

Comment: did you get it working? I found a github python library, https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive

Comment: Hey, thanks for this.  I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of the OneDrive API there is pretty [solid documentation](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/master/auth/msa_oauth.md) on how to implement the OAuth 2.0 standard from scratch.  Following what that doc lays out should make the authentication flow in your application pretty straight-forward.